# how to edit a crontab file using sed or awk where I replace a line for a pattern or else leave the line as it is

Tags: awk

I have sample crontab file as below. I want to write a script to comment the job having `H5TEMP`, if it is not commented. It should be commented with `#HC#`. The file should have all the lines but only change the line which matches the criteria. I want to pass two parameters to this script.

- `H5TEMP` - The word to search for,
- `#HC#` - Comment tag

eg. `disable_cronjob.sh H5TEMP #HC#`

Current file:

```
#=====================================
#Backup Status Report H5TEMP
0 8 * * * /app/oracle/admin/scripts/backup_report.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 

0 8 * * * /app/oracle/admin/scripts/backup_report.sh H5TEMP > /dev/null 2>&1
#=====================================
```

Output file:

```
#=====================================
#Backup Status Report H5TEMP
0 8 * * * /app/oracle/admin/scripts/backup_report.sh > /dev/null 2>&1

#HC#0 8 * * * /app/oracle/admin/scripts/backup_report.sh H5TEMP > /dev/null 2>&1
#=======================================
```

I tried with the below command, it only changes the required line. But I need to have the file exactly as above:

```
awk '/H5TEMP/ && ! /^#/ { print "#HC#" $0 }' < file
```

Can I change the crontab file directly? If not then will create temporary file and update crontab file.

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/crontab` is not meant for automated manipulation. This can get fragile and dangerous especially if multiple concurrent software packages manipulating it.

For automated manipulation of cron jobs you are highly encouraged to make usage of the folder `/etc/cron.d` (and friends). Having a single cronjob per file there, you can easily manipulate them by adding, overwriting or deleting files. `/etc/cron.d` is meant for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to awk came close. Try this:
`awk '/^[^#].*H5TEMP/ {printf "#HC#"}  {print $0}'  < file`
(Not using that `&& !` syntax because it does not seem to be portable)

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash

# validate arguments here ...

temp=$(mktemp)
crontab -l | 
awk -v pattern="$1" -v comment="$2" '
    BEGIN {exit_status = 1}
    $0 ~ pattern && $0 !~ "^"comment {$0 = comment $0; exit_status = 0}
    {print}
    END {exit exit_status}
' > "$temp" && 
crontab "$temp"
```

Comment: Downvoted for obnoxious bash-shebang.  And then, there isn't even a bashism used from what I can tell, so it's just unportable for no reason at all...